# "not a vengeance party" scene

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

I *think* this scene was from a military sf or fantasy book, but I can't place it.

---

Commander: Well, you've seen what they did to [men's names]. How many of you want a chance to get back at the sons of bitches who did that?

[several volunteers jump forward]

Commander: Okay, you men turn in your weapons and get back inside. Anyone else who feels the way they do can stay behind too. We are not organising a vengeance party, this is about delivering justice.

Comment: The scene does not ring a bell, but I'm keeping an eye on the Q because it sounds like the kind of book I'd read ;)

Comment: i'm leaning towards andre norton's "star soldiers"; if no one comes up with anything i'll dig up my copy and reread it. it's very well worth reading anyway :)

Comment: @Martin: I seem to remember that scene, but I haven't read Norton. Could that be Heinlein? Maybe Starship Troopers? What else have I read recently? `<walks_to_shelf/>` Lots of stuff by Alistair Reynolds, some Niven. Does that ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Definitely not *Starship Troopers*. It sounds like something Lois McMaster Bujold might write, maybe.

Comment: might be heinlein, but if so, one of the juveniles - those are the only ones i've read recently. definitely not niven, and i haven't read any reynolds, so not that either. another possibility is somewhere in the "song of ice and fire" books, since i reread those this year, but though it sounds like it would fit in there i can't think of a specific scene where it could have played out.

Comment: @Martin: To further narrow it down, I haven't read "ice and fire". Assuming I really remember that scene (rather than thinking I am) I guess that leaves Heinlein then. However, I have ploughed my way through many of Heinlein's books in the last year (had to catch up, since I missed him as a youth), and would have little chance to find anything in those.

Comment: Another couple of possibilities are David Drake and Jerry Pournelle. I could see either of them writing this.

Comment: Actually...it occurs to me that the line about delivering justice doesn't sound so much like soldiers as like police. Are you sure they were military?

Comment: fairly sure it was military - i remember the context as "enemies" rather than just "bad guys". it's annoying me that i can't place this, because i'm sure it's a book i read sometime in the last two years!

Comment: also, definitely not drake or pournelle - i've read very little by either author

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206875/short-story-about-cities-being-connected-by-a-conveyor-belt (about the radio play version)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's Heinlein, "The Roads Must Roll" (I read it about 25 years ago and that scene stuck in my head too).

> "You saw Hughes brought in-how many of you want a chance to kill the
>   louse that did it?" Three of the cadets reacted almost at once,
>   breaking ranks and striding forward. Gaines looked at them coldly.
>   "Very well. You three turn in your weapons, and return to your
>   quarters. Any of the rest of you that think this is a matter of
>   private revenge, or, a hunting party, may join them."